# How to update embeded matplotlib in Gtk at runtime?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk3

i want to update matplotlib histogram after selecting an image with gtk file chooser but nothing happen, i try remove the plot then add again but still not work, what should i do ?
this is my code [main.py](https://gofile.io/?c=zaIXJb)

```py
def setup_plot(self):
        # /home/jimmyferiawan/Desktop/PengolahanCitra/TugasGrayscale/gs1.png = https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/10/17bf55548e331fab0803d55377001622-full.jpg
        img = cv2.imread('/home/jimmyferiawan/Desktop/PengolahanCitra/TugasGrayscale/gs1.png',0)
        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
        a.hist(img.ravel(), 256, [0,256])

        self.sw.set_border_width(10)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(f)
        self.sw.add(canvas)
```

Comment: Hello! Does not work is not really helpful to understand the problem. Please clarify if you get an error (in this case add the full traceback in the question) or if you have an unexpected behaviour (in this case, tell what it is)

Comment: It is better to have all your code posted on StackOverflow, that way we don't have to go to other sites. And if those sites disappear, other people coming here can't find your code anymore.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't find a cv2 to import.